# CH x $\neg$ CH?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

1. Is any consistent first order extension of $\sf ZFC + CH$ interpretable in a consistent first order extension of $\sf ZFC + \neg CH$?
2. Is any consistent first order extension of $\sf ZFC + \neg CH$ interpretable in a consistent first order extension of $\sf ZFC + CH$?

Where $\sf CH$ is the *continuum hypothesis*.

If 1 is true and 2 is not, then $\sf ZFC + \neg CH$ is true!

If 2 is true and 1 is not, then $\sf ZFC + CH$ is true!

If both are true, then we have a dilemma?

If both are false, then the method is irrelevant?

> Where we are?

Comment: Not sure to understand... If 1 is true... does not imply that in the theory (call it $T$) where we are interpreting $\mathsf {ZFC + CH}$ we have that both $\mathsf {CH}$ and $\mathsf {¬CH}$ are true ? If so $T$ is not consistent, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why would it? You can interpret a theory in which a sentence holds without actually believing that sentence.

Comment: @Zuhair None of this has to do with the *truth* of $\mathsf{CH}$, though - I don't see why you're claiming that link.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, No! because we are speaking of interpretations, for example let T be ZFC + CH (which is an extension of ZFC + CH), now its clear that ZFC +CH is interpretable in ZFC + ~CH, and of course it is also interpretable in ZFC + CH, no inconsistency.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, *truth* is not a clear concept as regards set theory. Here this question reflects *maximality* principle, if CH proves to limit extendibility of ZFC then it is false. We need to study the maximal number of sets we can, not the minimal.

Comment: Except that's not what you've written. You've written that one sentence implies another. Also, keep in mind that not everyone takes the same foundational stance ($\mathsf{V=L}$ has its proponents, although it's a very minority view). You should write what you actually mean.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I don't know where I missed writing things, I clearly said "extensions" of, and I'm clearly speaking about limitation of extendiblity of a theory if a certain statement is held. Anyhow. From your answer I know that the answer is the third option, i.e. the dilemma option, so this calls for a better characterization of the maximality principle than the above-mentioned one I've stated.

Comment: @Zuhair " I don't know where I missed writing things" Because you wrote as the conclusion e.g. of (2) but not (1): "Therefore $\mathsf{CH}$ is true." If I write "Is [thing] the case? Because if so, $\mathsf{CH}$ is true," where [thing] is expressible in the language of set theory, what that's understood to mean is that I claim I have a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of "[thing] implies $\mathsf{CH}$." You didn't mention maximality anywhere. Put another way: do you think someone who doesn't buy the maximality perspective would think that your (2) but not (1) would be convincing evidence of $\mathsf{CH}$?

Comment: If you'd said "If (2) but not (1), then that would constitute a strong argument for $\mathsf{CH}$ from a 'maximize' perspective," I'd have no objections. But what you've written isn't that.

Comment: Ah I see! Man that's subtle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get interpretations in both directions via a simple trick (using the obvious consistency assumptions).

Given a (consistent, computably axiomatizable) theory $\mathsf{A}$, consider the theory $\mathsf{ZFC+Con(A)}$; in any model $M$ of this theory by absoluteness we can pick out a canonical model of $\mathsf{A}$, namely the $L$-least model of $\mathsf{A}$ in the sense of $M$. This gives an interpretation of $\mathsf{A}$ in $\mathsf{ZFC+Con(A)}$, the shift to $L$ being used to make everything parameter-free.

*Keep in mind that just because $X\in L$ does not mean $X\models \mathsf{V=L}$.*

In particular, if $\mathsf{T}$ and $\mathsf{S}$ are extensions of $\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$ and $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ respectively then $\mathsf{T}$ is interpretable in $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH+Con(T)}$ and $\mathsf{S}$ is interpretable in $\mathsf{ZFC+CH+Con(S)}$.

(None of this bears on the question of whether $\mathsf{CH}$ is *true* or not, however; there's no particular tension here.)

Comment: I must accept the answer because it answered my question as its wrote. Now what if we demand mutual interpretability of the extensions, what I mean is that if we have ZFC + CH + T, then we can have a theory ZFC + \neg CH + K that is mutually interpretable with it. Would generally the same argument of yours would still apply. (notice your exact argument above won't apply because con(T) is stronger than T)